# Lightning Web Components - I am having problems getting the PicklistValues for the Status field in the Campaign object

Tags: picklist, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have the following code

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
    import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
    
    import CAMPAIGN_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Campaign";
    import STATUS_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Campaign.Status";
    
    export default class CreateAdventure extends LightningElement {
    
        @track errorSt;
        @track statusOptions;
        
    
        @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CAMPAIGN_OBJECT })
        objectInfo;
    
        @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId", fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD })
        statusOptions;
        
        get recordTypeId() {
            let rtId = '';
            if (this.objectInfo.data) {
                const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
                rtId = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Adventure');
            } else if (this.objectInfo.error) {
                rtId = JSON.stringify(this.objectInfo.error);
            }
            return rtId;
        }
      
    
        get statusOptionsStr() {
            const sojson = JSON.stringify(this.statusOptions);        
            return sojson;
        }
```

I added the last function to see what the statusOptions was returning. And even though the recordTypeId is displaying correctly, the statusOptions is an empty object. Can someone help me with this?  I have tried many different combinations but I am still not getting the response I am expecting.

Comment: Does the status field have options configured for that specific record type that you are dealing with?

Comment: At this time all record types in Campaign have the same options. Is this the reason I am getting an empty object? Should I jut try getting the picklist with the default record type?  I was trying to code it for future changes (although there is no plan for changes).

Answer (score 0):

The values returned from the [`getPicklistValues()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values) wire adapter are returned in the `data` or `error` property as applicable. And that seems to be your issue here as why you are not able to view the values.

> If a property is decorated with `@wire`, the results are returned to the property’s `data` property or `error` property.

So as long as your Campaign Record Type has valid Status values, and that you have the correct `recordTypeId` value being passed in the `getPicklsitValues()` wire adapter, you will get the Status values without any issue. What you will need to instead change in your existing function is to return the `data` property. This is how your function should look like:

```
get statusOptionsStr() {
    const sojson = JSON.stringify(this.statusOptions.data); // notice it now returns data        
    return sojson;
}
```

Comment: I added the data property, although I thought that the full object would be stringified with data or error. Now it says that sojson is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct record type id? Have you tried with the default record type id? Check [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/252471/54851) to see details as how you can pass the default record type id.

Comment: I am retrieving the recordTypeId through the getRecordTypeInfos wire, and it sends back the correct id.  I just tried the getPicklistVaues with a hardcoded id and it works fine. -- i got the id from the console.log(recordTypeId). Why is it not working with '$recordTypeId' but it works if I hardcode it? does my recordTypeId need to have a value parameter?

Comment: I tried setting a VALUE parameter on recordTypeId, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: There must be something else going around then. I can confirm that the approach above works perfectly fine as long as the request arguments to the adapter are fine.

Comment: Darn, I don't know what is going on. I guess I will just have to leave LWC for a later date. Now I do get an object back with getPicklistValues and defaultRecordTypeId as a parameter, but then I can't get the values from it. When I stringify the object I get back I can clearly see the 'values' key, but if I refer to it with notation .data.values it says the whole object is undefined .... :(  I give up!

Comment: Take a look at this [lwc-recipe](https://bit.ly/2W5JXme) on this topic. Hope that will help you.

Comment: No, that doesn't help, because it's hardcoding the recordTypeId. That also works for me. What doesn't work is when I use a variable instead. But thanks for trying, I appreciate your time.